# JSF (Mojarra) 1.2 causing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError on deploy

Tags: java, maven, jsf, jboss5.x

After converting a JavaEE 6 legacy project to Maven, I am having a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` **when the JBossAS 5.1 tries to initialize mojarra** on my application context (and only for my context). The *original* project used "manual" dependency management and used Apache Ant to make the builds.

I have success to convert the project to Maven. I used the same versions of the dependencies and I compiled and build the package with success. During the application deploy, the **JBossAS 5.1 freezes** on the line:

```
INFO  [config] Initializing Mojarra (1.2_16-20110421-1728-SNAPSHOT) for context '/myApp'
```

And after 8 minutes, I get the following error:

```
WARN  [ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:javax.el.ELResolver
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:45)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.<init>(StringBuffer.java:91)
    at java.net.URLStreamHandler.toExternalForm(URLStreamHandler.java:473)
    at java.net.URL.toExternalForm(URL.java:901)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryHandler.getRealURL(ZipEntryHandler.java:259)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.DelegatingHandler.getRealURL(DelegatingHandler.java:222)
    at org.jboss.virtual.VFSUtils.getRealURL(VFSUtils.java:1064)
    at org.jboss.classloading.spi.vfs.policy.VFSClassLoaderPolicy.getProtectionDomain(VFSClassLoaderPolicy.java:651)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:547)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:532)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:530)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:507)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:134)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:131)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:452)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:251)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:150)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:265)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1119)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:798)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:441)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:63)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:572)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:532)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:530)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:507)
15:34:06,498 ERROR [[/horas]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossJSFConfigureListener
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! GC overhead limit exceeded
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:214)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:200)
    at org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossJSFConfigureListener.contextInitialized(JBossJSFConfigureListener.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4393)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:45)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.<init>(StringBuffer.java:91)
    at java.net.URLStreamHandler.toExternalForm(URLStreamHandler.java:473)
    at java.net.URL.toExternalForm(URL.java:901)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryHandler.getRealURL(ZipEntryHandler.java:259)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.DelegatingHandler.getRealURL(DelegatingHandler.java:222)
    at org.jboss.virtual.VFSUtils.getRealURL(VFSUtils.java:1064)
    at org.jboss.classloading.spi.vfs.policy.VFSClassLoaderPolicy.getProtectionDomain(VFSClassLoaderPolicy.java:651)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:547)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:532)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:530)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:507)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:134)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:131)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:452)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:251)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:150)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:265)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1119)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:798)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:441)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:63)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:572)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:532)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:530)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:507)
```

This is my **pom.xml**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>br.com.cpny</groupId>
<artifactId>minhaApp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Minha Aplicação</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.14</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-impl</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-seam</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.ga</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.envers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-envers</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.GA-hibernate-3.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>minhaApp</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <optimize>true</optimize>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <!-- Repositório JBoss / Hibernate / JPA / EHCache -->
    <repository>
        <id>repository.jboss.org-public</id>
        <name>JBoss repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>

    <!-- Sourceforge -->
    <repository>
        <id>sourceforge</id>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/sourceforge/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <!-- EHCache -->
    <repository>
        <id>terracotta-releases</id>
        <url>http://www.terracotta.org/download/reflector/releases</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: inspect memory and figure out what piece of code consumes most of the memory, or if you think your code is fine and you are running on low memory increase memory

Comment: My code is fine because this error only happens **after the conversion to Maven**. If I build the project using Ant, the deploy works fine. I will try to inspect the memory.

Comment: AFAIK JBoss 5 is not Java EE 6 compliant and you're using JSF 1.1 when you want/need JSF 1.2.

Comment: Well, I don't know why, but when I removed the lib `el-api.jar`, which is a dependency of `jboss-seam`, from `war`, the application deployed. However, I am not convinced about this solution and I will look into this problem a little bit more.

Comment: Thanks guys! Problem solved! I posted and answer how I solved this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved!**

First of all, I am using **JBoss Seam**. The dependency is declared on `pom.xml` this way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-seam</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

But, the dependency of JBoss Seam, includes `el-api.jar` (version 1.0) and when I build my project with Maven, this library go in `WEB-INF/lib` folder. However, if you take a look in `<JBOSS_HOME>/common/lib` you will find another `el-api.jar`. Somehow there is a problem putting your own library in war file with the one that came with JBoss AS.

So, we have to take out from war file the `el-api.jar`. To do this, I've added an exclusion on my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-seam</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
             <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
             <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

And the deploy works absolutely fine... until I try to open the index! When I accessed the index, **another error**! This one:

```
ERROR [facelets.compiler] (http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8180-1) Missing Built-in Tag Libraries! Make sure they are included within the META-INF directory of Facelets' Jar
ERROR [facelets.viewhandler] (http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8180-1) Error Rendering View[/login.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: Function 'rich:element' not found
    at org.jboss.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.visit(ExpressionBuilder.java:187)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.SimpleNode.accept(SimpleNode.java:129)
    at org.jboss.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.prepare(ExpressionBuilder.java:138)
    at org.jboss.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:152)
    at org.jboss.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createValueExpression(ExpressionBuilder.java:206)
```

The exception points a problem in facelets and missing tag libraries. But upgrading facelets **from version 1.1.14 to version 1.1.15** solved this problem too and the application is working fine so far.

Facelets dependency declared in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.15</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```